# Start/end transaction in separate EJB methods

Tags: java, database, ejb, cluster-computing, bean-managed-transactions

I developed a typical enterprise application that is responsible for provisioning customer to a 3rd party system. This system has a limitation, that only one thread can work on a certain customer. So we added a simple locking mechanism that consists of `@Singleton` which contains a `Set` of customerIds currently in progress. Whenever a new request comes for provisioning, it first checks this `Set`. If cusotomerId is present, it waits otherwise it adds it to the `Set` and goes into processing.

Recently it was decided, that this application will be deployed in cluster which means that this locking approach is no longer valid. We came up with a solution to use DB for locking. We created a table with single column that will contain customerIds (it also has a unique constraint). When a new provisioning request comes we start a transaction and try and lock the row with customerId with `SELECT FOR UPDATE` (if customerId does not exist yet, we insert it). After that we start provisioning customer and when finished, we commit transaction.
Concept works but I have problems with transactions. Currently we have a class `CustomerLock` with `add()` and `remove()` methods that take care of adding and removing customerIds from `Set`. I wanted to convert this class to a stateless EJB that has bean-managed transactions. `add()` method would start a transaction and lock the row while `remove()` method would commit transaction and thus unlocked the row. But it seems that start and end of transaction has to happen in the same method. Is there a way to use the approach I described or do I have to modify the logic so the transaction starts and ends in the same method?

CustomerLock class:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class CustomerLock {

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction tx;

    public void add(String customerId) throws Exception {
        try {
            tx.begin();
            dsApi.lock()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void remove(String customerId) throws Exception {
        try {
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerProvisioner class excerpt:

```
public abstract class CustomerProvisioner {

    ...

    public void execute(String customerId) {
        try {
            customerLock.add(customerId);

            processing....

            customerLock.remove(customerId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

StandardCustomerProvisioner class:

```
@Stateless
public class StandardCustomerProvisioner extends CustomerProvisioner {

    ...

    public void provision(String customerId) {
        // do some business logic
        super.execute(customerId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that "start and end of transaction has to happen in the same method" ? There is quite strange commit call in finally block BTW. When everything goes fine (no exception thrown), it will commit transaction and DB lock will disappear so far (it's transaction-wide).

Comment: sorry... that 'finally' was not ment to be there :) I corrected the code.

Comment: Excerpt = snippet, those are usually not detailed enough. What is "CustomerProvisioning" ? Another EJB?

Comment: It's a little more "twisted" but technically yes. Elaborated a little more... We have three implementations of CustomerProvisioning abstract class.

Comment: The only thing I can see now that there is a mix of container managed transactions and bean managed transactions going on, but I don't see how things are wired up together at all.

Comment: I realized my mistake now :) Thank you all for comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gimby noted, you should not mix container-managed and bean-managed transactions. Since your StandardCustomerProvisioner has no annotation like "@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)" - it uses container-managed transactions, and REQUIRED by default.

You have 2 options to make it work:

1) To remove "@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)" with UserTransaction calls and run CMT

2) Add this annotation ("@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)") to StandardCustomerProvisioner and use transaction markup calls from this method, so all the invoked methods use the same transactional context. Markup calls from CustomerLock should be removed anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... Yes I totally misunderstood how this transactions work in container. It got me thinking only after a couple of comments to realize the above solution. I guess I just needed a little 'brainstorming' :) Thank you all for replies! Cheers